# How to add to end of SED without adding a row

Tags: sql, linux

I am trying to add an insert line to 22 million rows using sed. My current commands are;

```
sed -i 's/ //g' test.txt (Removes any spaces)
sed -i ':;N;$!b;s/\n/");\n/g' test.txt (Adds "); to end of line)
sed -i -e "s/^/INSERT INTO TABLES (FIELD) VALUES (\"/" test.txt (Adds insert with (")
```

If I do it on a test with 10 rows it does it fine, whenever I run it on my main txt file with 22 million rows it does it as..

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (FIELD) VALUES ("123456
")
INSERT INTO TABLE (FIELD) VALUES ("567891011
")
```

this is causing a `"` to be added after the number

Im tryin to achieve it as INSERT INTO TABLE (FIELD) VALUES ("567891011")

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this suffice

```
sed 's/\s*//g' test.txt
sed 's/$/");/' test.txt
sed 's/^.\+$/INSERT INTO TABLES (FIELD) VALUES ("/' text.txt
```

Or you could just put it in a line as

```
sed 's/\s*//g; s/^.\+$/INSERT INTO TABLES (FIELD) VALUES ("\0");/' test.txt
```